# How to limit the results of a query and group them together,

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

[image: Tables:Sentences and Criminals]

I have the two tables pictured from a "city jail' DB, one is the sentences given to criminals and the other criminal information. I am trying to write a query the lists only the criminal_id, first and last names with more that one sentence (i.e. the criminal_id's that have more than one sentence_id associated with it).

I have tried this query but get an error.

```
select 
    criminals.last, sentences.criminal_id, 
    count(sentences.sentence_id) as 'Number of Sentences'
from
    criminals 
join 
    sentences on criminals.criminal_id = sentences.criminal_id
where 
    count(sentences.sentence_id) > 1
group by 
    criminals.last
order by 
    'Number of Sentences' desc;
```

I get this error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to go about this one.

Comment: Assuming `s.sentence_id` can never be null then `C0UNT(s.sentence_id)` is the same as `C0UNT(*)`. Are you *really* on SQL Server 2005, it's really old and out of support?

Answer (score 3):

Filtering on aggregates such as the count happen in the `HAVING` clause, so you may use this version:

```sql
SELECT c.last, s.criminal_id, C0UNT(s.sentence_id) AS [Number of Sentences]
FROM criminals c
INNER JOIN sentences s
    ON c.criminal_id = s.criminal_id
GROUP BY c.last, s.criminal_id
HAVING C0UNT(s.sentence_id) > 1
ORDER BY C0UNT(s.sentence_id) DESC;
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked, except I had to change c.criminal_id to s.criminal_id in the GROUP BY clause. Thank you, very helpful!

Comment: Yes, you right, that was a typo.